# NameError in RequestsController#create, undefined local variable or method `request_params' for #<RequestsController:0x5635d28>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having an issue with my rails application. Basically I'm trying to make a simple website where people can apply for jobs. When the user clicks "show" on the jobs page (the page consists of a table of job offers)to show a particular job offer they are brought to a new page where more information is given on the job, and a text box where the person can write a message to make a request for the job.(I plan to make this a more efficient method such as a link to the candidates page but for the moment I'm keeping it as a simple text box where the candidate can comment). The problem arises when the candidate tries to submit the comment, I get the error mentioned above. Could it be an issue in the models as there is a number of relationships set up, i.e. a job has many requests, requests has many candidates etc, etc. I've gotten this message before and it was simply a case of fixing a variable name mistake, however I've been looking over this for a while, had it proof read by a friend and I still can't find the error.I would greatly appreciate any help!

**RequestsController**

```
 class RequestsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :authorise
 #set_request, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

   def create
      @job = Job.find params[:job_id]
      @request = @job.requests.new(request_params) <- Error highlights this line
      @request.candidate_id = @current_candidate.id       #sets the user_id FK
      @request.save #saves the @comment
                  # object to the comments table
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html{redirect_to @job}
        end         
   end

   private
   def comment_params 
   #This is the method ehich whitelists the data fields from the format
       params.require(:request).permit(:content, :job_id, :candidate_id)
   end
  end
```

**Request Model**

```
 class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :job, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :candidates
 end
```

**Candidate Model**

```
 class Candidate < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_secure_password
 validates_uniqueness_of:can_email

 belongs_to :request

 validates :can_name, presence: true
 validates :can_surname, presence: true
 validates :college, presence: true
 validates :can_email, presence: true
 validates :address, presence: true
 validates :experience, presence: true
 validates :password_digest, presence: true
 validates :college_year, numericality: { only_integer: true }

 end
```

**Job Model**

```
  class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sector

  has_many :requests, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :employer, presence: true
  validates :sector, presence: true
  validates :experience_req, presence: true
  validates :job_info, presence: true
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def comment_params
```

should be

```
def request_params
```

Comment: Just for this time :P

Comment: Spot on! Any idea why this has now created another error on the line below it "NoMethodError in RequestsController#create,
undefined method `candidate_id=' for #<Request:0x6762768>" I have a feeling this is a problem with the relationships?

Comment: The issue is that the request has many candidates so request.candidates is an array. you haven't got a field canidate_id

Comment: You could do `@request.candidates << @current_candidate` if this makes sense

Comment: I did this and it passed the error to the next line stating there is a ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in RequestsController#create,can't write unknown attribute `request_id'. I had a look at the relationships and now I'm lost again. I'll ask for you help one last time if you would be so kind!